# creating a json object in PHP

Tags: php, json

how do i create a json object similar to this in PHP?

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You create an array, and pass it to [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$stuff = array(
    'employees' => array(
        array('firstName' => 'John', 'lastName' => 'Doe'),
        ....
    )
);

echo json_encode($stuff);
```